# Could Yoda defend against a Force choke?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, yoda

We've seen Yoda deflect Sith lightning, but we haven't seen him defend against a Force choke.  What would happen if Vader or some other powerful Sith lord attempted to apply a Force choke against Yoda?

Comment: In the [*Jedi Knight*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_Jedi_Knight) video game series, when your enemy force chokes you, sending a force push towards them gets them to stop (and same if you force choke them). I doubt those gameplay mechanics are canon though.

Comment: I would imagine he'd pull out his lightsaber and chop you off at the knees